How to add entities to a join table using Entity Framework Core
I have two entities that share a many-to-many relationship (Agent and Patient). Entity Framework Core by default will create a join table (AgentPatient) for me.
I'm having trouble adding patients to an agent. Because when I add a Patient to the list of patients inside my Agent model, I want it to automatically update my AgentPatient table with the new relationship between entities created. So when I retrieve an agent from the database I can see the patients inside the patients list property.
Am I doing the wrong approach? Instead of trying to to add something to the Agent model should I be altering directly the AgentPatient table? Do I need to have a specific DbSet for my join table created by EF Core?
Here are my models:
Patient class:
public class Patient
{
    public Guid PatientID { get; set; }

    // Some other properties not important to the question
        
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; } = null;
    
    public List<AgentModel>? Agents { get; set; } = [];
}

Agent class:
public class AgentModel
{
    public Guid AgentId { get; set; } 
    
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; } = null;
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; } = null;

    // Navigation properties
    public List<Patient>? Patients { get; set; } = [];
     
    public DateTime DeletedAt { get; set; }
}

My mapping classes - Agent mapping:
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AgentModel> builder)
    {
        // Define table name (optional, defaults to class name)
        builder.ToTable("Agents");

        // Define primary key
        builder.HasKey(a => a.AgentId);

        // Configure relationships
        builder.HasMany(a => a.Patients)
               .WithMany(p => p.Agents);
    }
}

Patient mapping class:
public class PatientEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Patient> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Patients");

        // Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(p => p.PatientID);

        builder.HasMany(p => p.Agents)
               .WithMany(a => a.Patients);
    }
}

Feel free to ask for any other part of my code.

Your approach is correct. try to add the Patient to the Agent.Patients list and call SaveChangesAsync(). EF Core will automatically update the join table for the many-to-many relationship. You don't need to directly manipulate the join table or use Update() on the Agent.

you could try this code:
`var agent = await _context.Agents
.Include(a => a.Patients)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.AgentId == retrievedAgentId);
var patient = await _context.Patients
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PatientID == retrievedPatientId);
if (agent != null && patient != null && !agent.Patients.Contains(patient))
{
// Add patient to the agent's patient list only if not already present
agent.Patients.Add(patient);
// Save changes to update the join table automatically
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

}`

FYI: You don't need to declare your Lists as nullable if you're also going to initialize them.  For example List Patients {get;set;} = [];

EF will manage the AgentPatient table automatically, provided it is either responsible for the schema (code-first) or is mapped or matches convention to resolve the joining table. You do not need to declare a joining entity or have a DbSet for that entity. Using a joining entity is optional when the joining table consists of just the two FKs for the association (serving as a composite PK) The only time you need to declare and use a joining entity is when that joining table has additional properties. for example if you want to track/report a CreatedBy / CreatedAt on when a Patient was associated to an Agent. In this case you would use:
public virtual ICollection<AgentPatient> AgentPatients { get; } = [];

for the relationship so that you can get an .AgentPatient.CreatedBy, etc. but then to get the agent's patient details it would be .AgentPatient.Patient.Name for instance instead of the more convenient .Patient.Name with the default simplified association.
The main issues to check when working with "many" relationships and associations with EF include:

Ensure you eager load relationships before adding and removing items.

Here when you want to add or remove a patient from an agent, load the Agent with its patients collection:
var agent = await _context.Agents
    .Include(a => a.Patients)
    .SingleAsync(a => a.AgentId == agentId);

From here you can add and remove patients from the agent and EF will work out which AgentPatient records to add or delete.

References are everything in EF.

When associating entities, make sure you are working with tracked references. For instance when you associate a patient to an agent, you will be creating a AgentPatient record, but not necessarily be creating a Patient, rather associating an existing patient. A common pitfall new EF developers fall into is passing detached entities around. For instance having an UpdateAgent passing a collection of Patients then doing something like:
 var agentFromDb = await _context.Agents
     .SingleOrDefault(a => a.AgentId == agentId);
 agentFromDb.Patients = patients; // collection of detached patients

This has two key problems. #1 is that collection navigation properties should never be set after initialization. Instead, if you want to update a collection you should explicitly remove items that no longer apply, and add new associations. A good safety measure for entities is to remove setters entirely and auto-initialize the collection. So instead of:
public List<Patient>? Patients { get; set; } = [];

use:
public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; } = [];

virtual isn't necessary in EF Core, but it is a good reminder that the Patients collection will be overridden by entity tracking proxies. Point #2 is that if you have detached Patients, you don't want to add these to the Patients collection when associating existing rows. Even though these patients will have an ID set, if they aren't tracked by the DbContext they will be treated as new rows. Always associate existing rows using entity references the DbContext is tracking.

Ok it was a really good answer an thanks for teaching me some best practices. But I'm still not sure how do I add a patient to agent. Currently I'm retrieving an agent and a patient. So I assume they are both being tracked, and I do:
retrievedAgent.Patients.Add(retrievedPatient); _AgentRepository.UpdateAsync(retrivedAgent);
In the update async I'm basically saving the changes from the agent.

Yes, that should have created the AgentPatient record in the DB. Are you seeing something different or getting an exception? If the UpdateAsync is doing anything other than calling SaveChanges() then your repository code may be messing things up. Methods like _context.Set<Agent>.Update(agent) are used for updating detached entities and won't automatically manage related entities.
